# how to concatenate strings?

Tags: sql, oracle, string-aggregation

I'm on Oracle 10g and have the following table structure:
id,
paragraph

I want to group by id and concatenate the paragraphs. Each paragraph maybe 1500 characters or more.

When I try the wm_concat function, it complains that the string buffer is too small. I actually tried many of the examples on Oracle's website and they all fail with the error the string buffer is too small.

```
select id, wm_concat(paragraph) from paragraphs group by id
```

how do I solve this?

Comment: Did you try this solution (using row_number() and sys_connect_by_path): http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php#row_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm guessing the error is [`ORA-06502`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06502.php) and I can see how you might think that this doesn't apply to you in this situation.

However, this is the fault of `wm_concat`. This is a function and is constrained by Oracle's maximum varchar length in PL\SQL of 32,767 and 4,000 in standard SQL. Unfortunately, I assume, because of the way that wm_concat works or because of any lower constraints within the function or because you're using it in a select you can't get anywhere near the upper limit.

There is another option, [`stragg`](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:15637744429336), Tom Kyte's string aggregate function. If we look at the following comparison between the two you'll see that they perform almost identically and that the limit of both is a length of around 4,000, i.e. the standard SQL maximum. `stragg` is slightly faster, probably due to caching.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> create table tmp_test ( a varchar2(30) );

Table created.

SQL> insert into tmp_test
  2   select object_name
  3     from all_objects
  4          ;

81219 rows created.

SQL>  commit ;

Commit complete.

SQL>
SQL> declare
  2
  3    i integer := 1;
  4    k number(10);
  5    v_stragg varchar2(32767);
  6    v_test varchar2(32767) := '';
  7    start_time timestamp;
  8
  9  begin
 10
 11    select count(*)
 12      into k
 13      from tmp_test;
 14
 15    for i in 1 .. k loop
 16      start_time := systimestamp;
 17      begin
 18
 19        select wm_concat(a) into v_test
 20          from tmp_test
 21         where rownum < i;
 22
 23      exception when others then
 24        dbms_output.put_line('wm_concat: ' || length(v_test));
 25        dbms_output.put_line(systimestamp - start_time);
 26        exit;
 27     end;
 28    end loop;
 29
 30    for i in 1 .. k loop
 31      start_time := systimestamp;
 32
 33      select stragg(a) into v_test
 34        from tmp_test
 35       where rownum < i;
 36
 37      if v_test = 'OVERFLOW' then
 38        dbms_output.put_line('stragg: ' || length(v_stragg));
 39        dbms_output.put_line(systimestamp - start_time);
 40        exit;
 41      else v_stragg := v_test;
 42      end if;
 43    end loop;
 44  end;
 45  /
wm_concat: 3976
+000000000 00:00:00.005886000
stragg: 3976
+000000000 00:00:00.005707000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

As for solving it, I'm afraid you can't. Once you hit that limit that's it. You'll have to find a different way of doing your aggregations or ask yourself if you **really** need to.